# show segue from modal viewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, segue, rootviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a push/show segue from a UITableViewController that is presented modally. I am able to perform a push segue from a row in the tableview, but it is delayed. I know it has something to do with the navigation hierarchy stack, and I have tried many things like resetting the rootViewController but am not having any luck...thanks for any help!

```
// present place tableViewController ---> modally
    func handleShowPlacesVC() {
        let vc = PlacesTableVC()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } 


// show details tableViewController ---> push segue from tableview
    func handleShowCurrentUserPlaceDetailsVC() {
        let vc = CurrentUserPlaceDetailsVC()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Why not dismiss the tableVC from the parent VC and then show the segue from the parent VC?

Comment: I tried that and it still gives me a little glich...I do have a class MainNavigationController: UINavigationController being called in my AppDelegate...would that cause this??

Comment: Embed your table view controller to the navigation controller. And that's it.

Comment: I am building everything programmatically...

Comment: Are you perhaps running any API calls on the new VC displayed after the segue?

Comment: I am running GooglePlaces API to populate the UITableViewVC, but then I want to push to a detailed view and show data that was pulled into the UITableView. So I am passing GMSPlace data from the picker, to a TableView, then to the Detailed VC.